# Branch Office Server vs VPN

Tags: vpn, network-design

Historically our branch offices have had their own servers to do DNS, Active Directory and a few other services. But the number of people working out of our branch office has shrunk to about 4 people.

From head office we provide VPN access to all our remote users. I am proposing that instead of providing a server (and maintaining it) each user in this office instead uses VPN.

Email, File and Database access will be provided by head office in either configuration.

My question is how many users can work in the branch office before it becomes unworkable and I would need a server with site to site VPN?

Comment: we also have branch offices and VPN (openVPN) file access for branch employees to home base was dreadfully slow. 20x20 mbps across the internet when most people are used to 1000 mbps LAN connections to the server. Ended up setting up a local box at the branch office then running file server sync's every 15 mins over SSH; seems to be working great, no complaining so far.

Comment: Define "unworkable" ....